# Java insists on changing both variables

Tags: java, setter, accessor

When running my MVC model application, a Singleton instance of `ApplicationModel` is created.

When running the main method in my controller class, a `List<Shop>` is assigned to `shops` using `setShops()`. If `shopsDefault = null`, `setShops()` will also continue to assign the same `List<Shop>` to `shopsDefault`.

So far, so good.

However, when I call `sortShopsByName()` - which as you can see below uses `setShops()` - both `shops` AND `shopsDefault` become sorted! Why does it not just sort `shops` as intended?

My `ApplicationModel` Class...

```
import java.util.*;

public class ApplicationModel {

    //static variables
    private static ApplicationModel instance = null;

    //instance variables
    private List<Shop> shops;
    private List<Shop> shopsDefault;

    //constructors
    private ApplicationModel() {}

    //getInstance method
    public static ApplicationModel getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ApplicationModel();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    //getters and setters
    public List<Shop> getShops() {
        return shops;
    }

    public void setShops(List<Shop> shops) {
        this.shops = shops;
        if (this.shopsDefault == null) {
            this.shopsDefault = shops;
        }
    }

    public List<Shop> getShopsDefault() {
        return this.shopsDefault;
    }


    //Shop methods
    public void sortShopsByName() {
        List<Shop> shops = this.getShops();
        Collections.sort(shops);
        this.setShops(shops);
    }

    public void returnShopsToDefaultOrder() {

        List<Shop> shopsDefault = this.getShopsDefault();
        setShops(shopsDefault);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you only ever set both variables to a single instance of `List<Shop>`.  When that instance is sorted, it's sorted.  Any reference pointing to it will reflect that.

Comment: "If `shopsDefault = null`, `setShops()` will also continue to assign **the same `List<Shop>`** to `shopsDefault`." **The same list.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you assign `shops` to `shposDefault`, they both reference the same instance. Changes made to the instance via either instance will, thus, be visible via both references.

If this is not the intended behavior, you could copy the `shops` list when setting `null`. E.g.:

```
public void setShops(List<Shop> shops) {
    this.shops = shops;
    if (this.shopsDefault == null) {
        this.shopsDefault = new ArrayList<>(shops);
    }
}
```

Comment: Annoyed with myself for not spotting this! Thank you to all those that answered!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the same list. If you want different lists, make a copy when you assign it to shopsDefault (i.e. `new ArrayList<Shop>(shops)`).

Answer (score 1):

In this code you're setting both members to the same list reference:

```
this.shops = shops;
if (this.shopsDefault == null) {
   this.shopsDefault = shops;
}
```

If you want to separate them use the following:

```
this.shops = shops;
if (this.shopsDefault == null) {
   this.shopsDefault = new ArrayList<Shop>(shops);
}
```